# JS Slider Browser e.t.c

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem with my slider on [HERE](http://i.gavrecky.sk/index2.php). This slider working only in firefox but on other browser is full slider on the right page. My friends advised me thats i have delete overflow: hidden; from #Slider but if i do it show me down scroll bar http://pasteboard.co/U8IeB5Y.png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Slider {
  margin-top: -75px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Your container needs a width, otherwise your children set the width.

Comment: No problem. Remember to get your foundations figured out! I recommend you try teamtreehouse.com!